# Pancretic Acinar Cell - ATP, calcium concentration data

Tags: cell-biology, mitochondria

I need to find a decent source of data for concentration of ATP and calcium in the pancreatic acinar cell.

So far all I can find is ATP or calcium 'levels' based on fluorescence , which are not accompanied by a value of concentration in moles/molar.

Is it possible to find this information in a specific book or website, to avoid trawling though vast amounts of literature?

Comment: Have you tried asking on Biology as well? I'll have a look to see if there's anything around in the literature that I can find too.

Comment: See http://www.pancreapedia.org/tools/methods/measurement-of-intracellular-calcium-concentration-in-pancreatic-acini

Answer (score 2):

In [this](http://www.jbc.org/content/278/11/9361.long) study, even though they have used fluorescence based method, they have reported concentrations.

> When we studied basal intracellular calcium concentrations in acini from control rats they were in the low nanomolar range (140 ± 5 nmol).

For ATP concentrations you can see [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20102715).

> Is it possible to find this information in a specific book or website, to avoid trawling though vast amounts of literature?

There is the [human metabolome database](http://www.hmdb.ca/metabolites/HMDB00538). However, it doesn't have data for all cell types. Either more studies are required or the database needs updation.

Similarly there is the [yeast metabolome database](http://www.ymdb.ca/) (*you may not require it for your query but just another piece of information that I thought is worth adding*).